# How can I combine the values from two publishers that are dependent on eachother?

Tags: stream, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive

I have the following methods

```
class A -> Flux<A> getAllA();
class B -> Mono<B> getB(A a);
class C -> Mono<C> getC(A a, B b)
```

Now Im trying to achieve the following using a Reactive Stream:

1. Retrieve all `A` objects
2. Create object `B` for every `A`
3. Create object `C` for every pair `A`,`B`

Anyone know what this would look like? I came up with the solution below but was hoping there is some more elegant approach.

```
getAllA()
.map(a -> new Tuple2<A, B>(a, getB(a)))
.flatMap(t -> getC(t.getT1(), t.getT2()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple as:

```java
final Flux<C> flux = getAllA()
    .flatMap(
        a -> getB(a)
            .flatMap(
                b -> getC(a, b)
            )
    );
```

No need for `Tuples` at all. Behind the scenes the compiler will generate the necessary `invokedynamic` bytecode and `LambdaMetafactory` will do some heavy lifting for us to pass `a` to `getC(a, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your method `getB` returns `Mono<B>`, you will get `Mono<B>` in `t.getT2()`, so it seems that the code you provided in the example may not compile.

For a more elegant approach, consider utilizing `Mono.zip`.

```java
getAllA()
    .flatMap(a -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(a), getB(a)))
    .flatMap(tuple -> {
        A a = tuple.getT1();
        B b = tuple.getT2();

        return getC(a, b);
    })
```

But please pay attention that `Mono.zip` has the following behavior:

> An error or empty completion of any source will cause other sources to be cancelled and the resulting Mono to immediately error or complete, respectively.